# Swift 3 Programmatic Segue

Tags: ios, segue

I didn't want to complicate things with reference to my app, because I'm not able to implement this even at the simplest level.

On a fresh Xcode 8 beta 6 project I implemented a performSegue, but it doesn't work

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "startGame", sender: self)


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

As you can see, I have named my segue startGame. The app runs, but it doesn't segue. In fact, if i name the segue incorrectly in the self.performSegue, I get errors - so I know Xcode is able to find the segue, it's just not triggering it.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` might be to soon. There is no view on screen yet to perform the segue from.

Comment: FYI - Xcode 8 GM is out. Don't use a beta any more.